Image errorBuilder not called in InkWell
I want to use the errorBuilder callback when an image asset does not exist.
But it's not called when the Image is used with InkWell + Ink.
main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: InkWell(
            child: Ink.image(
              image: Image.asset(
                'assets/does-not-exist.png',
                // Not called:
                errorBuilder: (context, error, stackTrace) {
                  return Text('$error');
                },
              ).image,
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
              height: 400,
            ),
            onTap: () {},
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}



you can undelete if your posted answer is working

I finally made this class in replacement of Ink.image:
class _InkImage extends StatelessWidget {
  final ImageProvider image;
  final BoxFit? fit;
  final double? width;
  final double? height;
  final errorCompleter = Completer();

  _InkImage({
    super.key,
    required this.image,
    this.fit,
    this.width,
    this.height,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: errorCompleter.future,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return SizedBox(
            width: width,
            height: height,
            child: Text('${snapshot.error}'),
          );
        }
        return Ink.image(
          image: image,
          onImageError: (exception, stackTrace) {
            errorCompleter.completeError(exception, stackTrace);
          },
          fit: fit,
          width: width,
          height: height,
        );
      },
    );
  }
}


